# IOS : Tabbar item click again and again it is double Tab bar button item size

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I implemented tab bar with custom icon size.i find many solution from stack-overflow but i didn't getting any perfect solution for this issue.

**Issue** : when i click tabbar item again and again it's size double every time. and after click other tab it's size is  same as orignal size.

**See this Link For Issue :** [Screen Recording](https://vimeo.com/user92471914/review/304527598/897e195fce)

**My Code :**

```
import UIKit

class customTabBar: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tabHome2 = self.tabBar.items![2]
    tabHome2.image = UIImage(named: "ic_pick")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    tabHome2.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "ic_pick")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) 
    tabHome2.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -40, left: -10, bottom: 0, right: -10)

}
```

}

**My Design Requirement :**

[image]

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What does your code show? You say the problem is while tapping on the image, so share that code.

Comment: @Evgeniy not any code in tapping i just set above code and i click again and again in selected tab at that time i getting this issue.please see screen recording url i put in my question.

Comment: We need to see the method that is called when the button is tapped. You said it's occurring when the button is tapped; where is the code? Do you have any implementation for when tapping a tab bar item?

Comment: @JozemiteApps i did't any implementation on tapping a tab bar item.see my update question with UITabBarController full code.

Comment: Are you using a library to show that button in the middle? That is the one with the issue, right?

Comment: @JozemiteApps no i didn't use any library. tabHome2.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -40, left: -10, bottom: 0, right: -10) this code for middle button.

Comment: What happens if you take off the rendering mode methods? Since if you have the image at the right size, are these necessary?

Comment: @JozemiteApps Please see ScreenRecording in question. first time tab bar same as my requirement but when i click multiple time on middle button at that time this image zoom(double) automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Set Icons in assets. If you are using circular icons for tab bar item you should create following sizes for portrait mode:

- @1x : about 25 x 25 (max: 48 x 32)
- @2x : about 50 x 50 (max: 96 x 64)
- @3x : about 75 x 75 (max: 144 x 96)

Also you can refer this : [custom-icons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/)

> Set image inset from the property of Tabbar item.
>   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbbQv.png)

Comment: This is irrelevant as they said the size doubles every time they tap it. And it goes back to normal size when tapping another tab bar item.

Answer (score 0):

Your image insets are not balanced.
Try:

> tabHome2.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -20, left: -10, bottom: 20,
>   right: 10)

- Try to reproduce bug.
- Bug is gone.
- Find the right values. (Image edit might be needed.)
- Open a beer.

Comment: This is not solution because in my requirement middle tabbar item icon is large then other tabbar item icon.

Comment: @DixitAkabari I've had the same issue. The insets appear to cause the bug. In my case, I remember, it was the designer that fixed the image to avoid using the insets.

Comment: let me try this way  ask designer and change image.anyway thanks for your help.